# Pass subquery value to IN statement

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion

In one table named prefs, I have a column named "Value" of type clob that holds this value: 'T', 'L'

[image: Screenshot showing prefs record which holds lookup values]

I need to query table attendance_code to retrieve the records where column att_code values are either T or L. The att_code column is of type varchar2.

As a manual model query, this works fine:

```
SELECT id FROM attendance_code ac WHERE ac.att_code IN ('T', 'L')

Result:
  ID
1 4903
2 4901
```

**Attempt 1**

```
SELECT id FROM attendance_code ac WHERE ac.att_code IN (SELECT value from prefs WHERE name = 'AEADS|SAR|tdyCodes')

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

**Attempt 2**

```
SELECT id FROM attendance_code ac WHERE ac.att_code IN (SELECT dbms_lob.substr(value, 4000, 1) from prefs WHERE name = 'AEADS|SAR|tdyCodes')
```

This yields no error, but returns no rows.

**Attempt 3**
(Based on https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-and-pass-to-in-clause-of-select-statement)

```
select id from attendance_code ac where ac.att_code IN (
    select regexp_substr(value,'[^,]+', 1, level) from prefs WHERE name = 'AEADS|SAR|tdyCodes' 
    connect by regexp_substr(value, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null );

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

**Attempt 4**

```
select id from attendance_code ac where ac.att_code IN (
    select regexp_substr(dbms_lob.substr(value, 4000, 1),'[^,]+', 1, level) from prefs WHERE name = 'AEADS|SAR|tdyCodes' 
    connect by regexp_substr(dbms_lob.substr(value, 4000, 1), '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null );

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 1
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
```

I have also tried changing the value in the prefs table to just T,L (removing the single quotes) and running all of the above against that, to no avail.

What is the proper way to do this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hierarchical query` with **removed single quotes** as follows:

```
SELECT ID
FROM ATTENDANCE_CODE AC
WHERE AC.ATT_CODE IN (
        SELECT
            REPLACE(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(
            (SELECT value from prefs WHERE name = 'AEADS|SAR|tdyCodes'), 
            '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)), '''', '') FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(
            (SELECT value from prefs WHERE name = 'AEADS|SAR|tdyCodes'), 
            '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
    );
```

or simplify the above query with the `CTE` as following:

```
WITH DATAA ( VALS ) AS (
    SELECT VALUE
      FROM PREFS
     WHERE NAME = 'AEADS|SAR|tdyCodes'
)
SELECT ID
FROM ATTENDANCE_CODE AC,
     DATAA D
WHERE AC.ATT_CODE IN (
        SELECT
            REPLACE(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(D.VALS, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)), '''', '')
        FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(D.VALS, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
    );
```

Example with `Dual` as following:

> ```
> SQL> SELECT DUMMY FROM DUAL AC
>   2  WHERE
>   3      'T' IN (
>   4          SELECT
>   5              REPLACE(TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(
>   6              (SELECT q'#'T', 'L'#' FROM DUAL), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)), '''', '')
>   7              FROM DUAL
>   8          CONNECT BY
>   9              REGEXP_SUBSTR((
>  10                  SELECT q'#'T', 'L'#' FROM DUAL), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
>  11      );
>
> DUMMY
> -------
> X
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: I had to modify your suggestions above just a bit, converting value from clob....     dbms_lob.substr(value, 4000, 1). Your solution works perfectly otherwise! Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't store delimited values in a string; put them in another table (where you can have one row per item) with a foreign key referencing to the row in the parent table (for example: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1aba46065c48fe495eb87af728f3cd62)) or use a collection and a nested table.

An example of this second option is:

```sql
CREATE TYPE char_list IS TABLE OF CHAR(1);
```

Then

```sql
CREATE TABLE prefs (
  id   NUMBER(10,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  SchoolId NUMBER(10,0),
  UserId   NUMBER(10,0),
  Value    char_list,
  YearID   NUMBER(4,0)
) NESTED TABLE value STORE AS prefs__value;
```

So for your sample data:

```sql
INSERT INTO prefs ( id, name, schoolId, UserId, value, YearID )
VALUES ( 262806, 'AEADS|SAR|tdyCodes', 109, 0, char_list( 'T', 'L' ), 29 );

CREATE TABLE attendance_code ( id, att_code ) AS
SELECT 4903, 'L' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4902, 'X' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4901, 'T' FROM DUAL;
```

Your query would be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   attendance_code
WHERE  att_code MEMBER OF ( SELECT value FROM prefs WHERE name = 'AEADS|SAR|tdyCodes' );
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> |   ID |
> | ---: |
> | 4903 |
> | 4901 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=712b8ff5cc24b7bc42f2bd6dea5aaa91)*

Comment: From a database design perspective, I completely agree with you - absolutely correct. In this case however, I am not able to modify the structure of the database so I have to work within it's existing design. Thank you for taking time to make this recommendation.